# Loop through while array and add more properties to items - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm running a query in PHP, looping through the items and adding them to an array;

```
$select_all_restaurants = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$rows = $select_all_restaurants -> num_rows;

$arr = array();
if($rows > 0) {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_restaurants)) { 
        $arr[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

How can I append data into `$arr` from another query and for each of the items in the array.
So if item1 has properties `id,name` from the first query, when I run the second query I want to add more properties to it eg `distance`. So in `$arr`item1 ends up with `id,name,distance`

The query I'm getting the other set of data is below;

```
$info = get_driving_information($address1, $address2);
echo $info['distance'];
echo $info['time'];
```

Also I'm getting `$address1`from the original query.

This is what I've tried;

```
$select_all_restaurants = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$rows = $select_all_restaurants -> num_rows;

$arr = array();
if($rows > 0) {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_restaurants)) {

$info = get_driving_information($rows['address1'], $address2);
// I get two properties from this query
$info['distance'];
$info['time'];

// How do I add these 2 properties for every item in $arr?
//
        $arr[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

Please advise

Comment: It is much more proper, performant and easy to make it at SQL server side.

Comment: Can you implement it and avise

Comment: Are you asking the same question a second time? It was this a couple of hours ago: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627158/loop-through-and-array-and-append-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append the values to your `$rows` object like

```
$arr = array();
if($rows > 0) {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_restaurants)) {
        $info = get_driving_information($rows['address1'], $address2);
        // I get two properties from this query
        $rows['distance'] = $info['distance'];
        $rows['time'] =  $info['time'];
        $arr[] = $rows;
    }
}
```